# Quaternion.Euler is behaving differently from what I would explain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I don't really have a problem, just a question. I am working on a Unity project with C#.

Here is a piece of code that does exactly what I need:

```
Vector3 origPath = (MovingTo - unityObject.transform.position);
origPath = Quaternion.Euler(0, 360 - Angle, 0) * origPath;
path = path * Time.deltaTime * speed;
```

Which is to figure out the path an object should take to reach a specific Vector3 destination (MovingTo). Then it gets rotated because I am using GameObject.Translate later.

Now when the code gets changed for this:

```
Vector3 origPath = Quaternion.Euler(0, 360 - Angle, 0) * (MovingTo - unityObject.transform.position);
path = path * Time.deltaTime * speed;
```

The variable origPath has a very differently value at the end of those lines, as if the quaternion.Euler call behaved in a totally different way.

I would like to understand why that happens, because the behavior for the second code block is far from my needs, and I just spent a lot of time debugging it until i found the fix, which is the first block. I want to know why exactly that is a fix.

Comment: did you mean `path = origPath * Time.deltaTime * speed` ?

Comment: no, the other variable called "path" is unrelated to the events, and has no direct link with origPath until later (it gets compared). I simply added that last line to the blocks because my breakpoint is on that line, to check the value of origPath.

Comment: Did you make sure to use the same values for `MovingTo, transform.position, Angle` in both test cases?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yes, the balues were exactly the same, up to the decimals. And the difference in the result was obvious, like several units of difference.

Comment: This is a *very sketchy guess* - maybe the expression `(MovingTo - unityObject.transform.position)` is not of type `Vector3`, and assignment makes a cast? Try an explicit cast before the multiply: `Vector3 origPath = Quaternion.Euler(0, 360 - Angle, 0) * (Vector3)(MovingTo - unityObject.transform.position);`

Comment: what is Angle, MovingTo and unityObject?

Comment: if they are in fact giving different results, it must be due to something that you have not explained in the question